# Getting the content of .CSV cell

Tags: python, csv

I’m having troubles reading a .CSV file even though i have tried to read the online python-doc. 
The thing is i have been using the xlrd module on python to read through xls file and it went superbly. 
Now i want to try with .CSV but i find things much more complicated.

When i wanted python to return the content of a cell(i,j) : sheet.Cell(i,j).value and it worked. End.

It's a ";" delimited csv.

Something like :

Ref;A;B;C;D;E;f

P;x1;x2;x3;x4...

L;y1;y2;y3

M;z1...

N:w1 ...

I want to display a list box containing a A,B,C,D ... 
And bind this list with a Cur_Selection function that will make some calculus within x,y,z,w of a selected ref A,B,C,D ...

That was very easy in xlrd. I don't get it here.

Can someone help ?

Comment: "I want to display ...". How? Console? Graphical toolkit?

Comment: I'm doing all of my gui with tkinter from python.

Comment: Then your question is too broad. Please state the exact problem and what you tried to resolve it. I assume that you already read https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you asking how to access the data in the csv? I typically parse csvs with a simple function with string manipulation methods. Works for me with rather small csv files which I generate in excel.

```
def parse_csv(content, delimiter = ';'):
  csv_data = []
  for line in content.split('\n'):
    csv_data.append( [x.strip() for x in line.split( delimiter )] ) # strips spaces also
  return csv_data

content = open(uri,'r').read()
list_data = parse_csv( content )
print list_data[2][1]
```

Comment: What id like to do is simple. I want to put the content of a cell in a variable in order to make some calculus with it. But i can't get the content of a cell. See what i mean ? I can display a entite row or column but not a single cell in the terminal.

Comment: But that ('printing a single cell') is exactly what above snippet does! Did you run it?

Comment: No i didn't run it yet. Is it supposed to print the cell in line 2 et column 1. Did inunderstand correctly the example ? Sorry for botherung you guys but i'm quiet new at programming :)